# World File Not Corresponding to Coordinates of Warped geoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I am attempting to change CRS for a TIFF with TFW.

Loaded OK. Warped OK. Overlays fine. Properties report correct origin etc.

However when creating a world file (Translate: -co worldfile=yes) the values that are entered are for the old CRS.

What remedial steps can I take?

Comment: Write your whole gdalwarp command and gdalinfo report of both the original image and the warped one. Or if you did not use gdalwarp explain what you have done.

Comment: Sorted. Missed the Target SRS field